# Active record efficient query to recreate a belongs_to through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a voting system.

Basically I have a challenge, with many challenge items. Every challenge item has many photos and people have to vote these photos. So I record these votes, that belong to a photo. Every vote has a fingerprint that identify the voter. So with the fingerprint I can have all the votes of a user. 
Now: I have to get the ids in form of array of the challenge items a user has already voted from a given challenge.

I pass two params: the fingerprint, that I use to return the array of votes, and the challenge.

I have these models

```
class Challenge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :challenge_items
  has_many :photos, :through => :challenge_items
  belongs_to :season
end

class ChallengeItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :challenge
  has_many :photos
  has_many :votes, :through => :photos
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :challenge_item
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :photo
end
```

A Vote belongs to a photo that belongs to a challenge.

I need to build the most efficient query that return me the challenge items id array from a vote array.

A belongs_to association cannot have a :through option

Now I use

```
challenge_photo_ids = Challenge.find(params["challenge"]).photos.map(&:id)
```

to get the ids of the photos of a challenge

```
  get_already_voted = Vote.where(voter_string: params["voter_string"]).map(&:photo_id)
```

To get the ids of the photos from the vote

```
@already_voted = challenge_photo_ids & get_already_voted
```

To get the photos of a challenge with a vote.
But now from these photo I need also to retrieve the challenge items...

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably didn't get what you want. Isn't anything like this? Given the `votes_ids`

```
ChallengeItem.joins(photos: :votes).
    where(challenge_id: challenge_id, votes: {id: votes_ids}).
    distinct.pluck(:id)
```

It's what I get from this sentence `I need to build the most efficient query that return me the challenge items id array from a vote array`

Comment: yes...

but to get the vote_ids I need to use

`votes_ids = Vote.where(voter_string: "21e8177a963f0422cb12e9f452faf3c4").map(&:id)`

and with your query I have the ids of all voted challenge items, but I need only the challenge items that belongs to a given challenge! So your query is ok, but I nee to add another two queries...

Comment: well, just add another clause to the where with the challenge id

Comment: Use pluck, it's faster: `votes_ids = Vote.where(voter_string: "21e8177a963f0422cb12e9f452faf3c4").pluck(:id)`

Comment: also, couldn't you add the voter_string to my query and avoid this query altogether?

Comment: Something like `ChallengeItem.joins(photos: :votes).
        where(challenge_id: challenge_id, votes: {voter_string:"21e8177a963f0422cb12e9f452faf3c4"}).
        distinct.pluck(:id)`

Comment: Prego Roberto :)